# Xamarin forms - iOS Inbox folder

Tags: ios, file, xamarin.forms

I need to load files inside the application using "open in" iOS command.

I have already import the correct Document Types and the "open in" button appears correctly 
but I can't see the loaded files inside the Inbox folder.

In an older app, I can see the Inbox folder inside the Document folder, but in this new app the Inbox folder was created inside the tmp folder.

How can I restore the "old" behavior?

Thank you! :)

[image]

Comment: You can show some code about this problem.

Comment: There isn't code.
I have enable the "open in" by adding the document types inside the info.plist, and I haven't do any others things.

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the version of your XamarinForms and iOS, and whether the new app and the old app are different. You can take a screenshot of the info.plist file you configured. In addition, you can elaborate on the inconvenience caused by such changes.